# Ember add-on random tests fail with "Can not call `.lookup` after the owner has been destroyed” after updating ember and dependencies

Tags: ember.js

I updated my add-on’s dependencies, and ember version to use octane (following ember guide). The add-on works correctly as it did before, but not the tests. A single random test (not always the same test) fails, and if I re-run the single test by itself, it passes. The random test failure error is always the same:

`` Can not call `.lookup` after the owner has been destroyed. ``

I’ve also tried running test related code-mods, but that resulted in more errors, in addition to the aforementioned random test error, so I reverted the code-mods. (I plan on updating tests to use the latest style but would rather do that in a separate effort, if possible).

I'd greatly appreciate any info on why this error occurs, or how I can get rid of it.

If it helps, I originally had these as part of my dependencies (before updating):

```
"ember-cli": "~3.0.4",
"ember-source": "~3.0.0",
"ember-cli-pretender": "1.0.1",
"ember-cli-qunit": "^4.3.2",
"ember-native-dom-helpers": "^0.6.2",
"ember-qunit-assert-helpers": "0.2.1",
"ember-qunit-nice-errors": "^1.2.0",
"ember-qunit-source-map": "^1.2.0",
"ember-sinon": "^2.1.0",
"ember-sinon-qunit": "^3.1.0",
"ember-test-selectors": "^0.3.9”,
```

I now have these as part of my dependencies (after my update):

```
"ember-cli": "~3.23.0",
"ember-source": "~3.23.1",
"ember-cli-pretender": "4.0.0",
"ember-native-dom-helpers": "^0.6.3",
"ember-qunit": "^4.6.0",
"ember-qunit-assert-helpers": "0.2.2",
"ember-qunit-nice-errors": "^1.2.0",
"ember-qunit-source-map": "^1.2.0",
"ember-sinon": "^5.0.0",
"ember-sinon-qunit": "^5.0.0",
"ember-test-selectors": "^5.0.0",
"qunit-dom": "^1.6.0”,
```

Comment: Hi bbis, and welcome to Stack Overflow. The above code is not enough to help you. Some of your code is not cleaning up after itself in willDestroy hook. Probably an event handler or some async code is being run after a test that runs it has already completed, calling the owner in the test after it was destroyed. It is likely not the test that is showing the error message, but some test before that. The reason your tests passed before is that this assertion is new, and is there to help you plug your memory / resource leak. A good place to start is to look for calls to owner.lookup.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Gaurav!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using setTimeout in "afterModel", the "this" of the route getting destroyed (so .lookup failed for service)

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.splashScreen.hide();
}, 500);
```

To fix that I moved "this" out of setTimeout

```
const splashScreen = this.splashScreen;
setTimeout(() => {
    splashScreen.hide();
}, 500);
```